# Keeping all elements aligned to the same grid and spanning multiple columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying out CSS3's flexbox for the first time and it seems promising, but I'm having some trouble getting it to behave.

Basically, I want flexbox to behave like a table but with an order property so I can tell it in the CSS what order to display the elements in the grid. Is this even possible with flexbox?

Here's the test page I created: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb838dwf/

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1">div 1</div>
  <div id="div2">div 2</div>
  <div>generic</div>
  <div id="div3">div 3</div>
  <div>generic</div>
  <div id="div4">div 4</div>
  <div>generic</div>
  <div>generic</div>
  <div>generic</div>
  <div>generic</div>
  <div>generic</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#main div {
    min-width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 1;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#main #div1 {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
    background-color: coral;
}
#main #div2 {
    -webkit-order: 5;
    order: 5;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#main #div3 {
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
#main #div4 {
    -webkit-order: 4;
    order: 4;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

You can see that #div3 has `flex: 2`, which means it should span two columns, but it's only taking up 1 column. Also, the 3 divs at the bottom (div1, div4, div2) aren't aligning to the same grid as the items above it. If I add `max-width: 25%` to the `#main div` style, it keeps everything to the same grid, but spanning columns doesn't work. I tried setting `max-width: 25%` for all divs and `max-width: none` for just #div3 (the one with flex:2) but that doesn't have an affect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's dissect a few of the things you wrote so we could clarify flexbox behavior.

---

> You can see that `#div3` has `flex: 2`, which means it should span two
>   columns, but it's only taking up 1 column.

`flex: 2` does not mean it should span two columns. This isn't like an HTML `colspan` attribute. (And even if it was, you have three other flex items ["table cells"] already occupying the three remaining columns, so how would `#div3` expand two columns? It would have to break out of the grid.)

The [**`flex`** property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/) is a shorthand for the [`flex-grow`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/), [`flex-shrink`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/) and [`flex-basis`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/) properties.

The `flex-grow` property controls how flex items will expand by *distributing remaining space* in the flex container. So by applying `flex: 2` you're saying you want the flex item to take twice as much remaining space than its siblings, not necessarily be double their size.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property), the `flex-grow` property:

> ...determines how much the flex item will grow relative to the rest of
>   the flex items in the flex container when positive free space is
>   distributed.

However, since you've given the container (`#main`) a `width: 100%`, and each flex item `min-width: 25%`, there is *no remaining space to distribute*. So nothing happens.

To illustrate this behavior, change the width of each flex item to 50px. This leaves extra space to distribute and `#div3` takes 2x as much. See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb838dwf/6/

---

> Also, the 3 divs at the bottom (div1,div4,div2) aren't aligning to
>   the same grid as the items above it.

Correct. They're not aligning because you applied `flex: 1` to them in `#main div`. This tells them to evenly distribute all remaining space among themselves.

---

> If I add `max-width: 25%` to the `#main div` style, it keeps
>   everything to the same grid, but spanning columns doesn't work. I
>   tried setting `max-width: 25%` for all divs and `max-width: none` for
>   just #div3 (the one with flex:2) but that doesn't have an affect.

What? You lost me.

---

> I want flexbox to behave like a table but with an order property so I
>   can tell it in the CSS what order to display the elements in the grid.
>   Is this even possible with flexbox?

Yes, it's possible.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
    <div>div 5</div>
    <div>div 6</div>
    <div>div 7</div>
    <div>div 8</div>
    <div>div 9</div>
    <div>div 10</div>
    <div>div 11</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#main div {
    flex: 0 0 150px; /* don't grow, don't shrink, stay at 150px */
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}

#main div:nth-child(2)  { order: -4; background-color: lightblue; }
#main div:nth-child(5)  { order: -3; background-color: lightgreen; }
#main div:nth-child(8)  { order: -2; background-color: lightyellow; }
#main div:nth-child(11) { order: -1; background-color: lightpink; }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb838dwf/4/

---

**Spanning multiple columns**

As mentioned above, the `flex` property is a shorthand for the `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` properties.

`flex-grow` tells flex items how to distribute available space, hence it is not a reliable tool for emulating the HTML `colspan` attribute. (The space available in the container and double the size of a flex item are unrelated lengths and not necessarily equal.)

However, the `flex-basis` property, which sets the initial size of a flex item, can be used to make flex items twice as wide, three times as wide, whatever.

In my code above, flex items are set to: `flex: 0 0 150px;` The third value represents `flex-basis`. So each box is set to 150px wide.

For a flex item to occupy two columns simply double that value.

Since `flex` cascades to all divs, we only need to adjust the `flex-basis` for targeted items.

```
#main div:nth-child(11) { flex-basis: calc(300px + 10px); } /* factoring in margin space */
#main div:nth-child(7)  { flex-basis: calc(450px + 20px); } /* factoring in margin space */
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb838dwf/5/ (expand window for effect)

Comment: `order:999` doesn't make ordering items any easier, in fact you're just introducing ambiguously large numbers that can be harder to understand (why is 998 at the top of the list?). `order` can have negative values, so the default of `0` is a pretty good choice. If you need something to move up, use `-1`, if you need it to move down use `1`. Additionally, similar to `z-index`, it's especially useful to use variables in a consistent location (preprocessors FTW) so that the overall order of elements can be described without having to find the individual selectors.

Comment: @zzzzBov, by setting a high value on the `order` property you actually remove the need to use negative numbers, and the ordering can start with 1. But there are some possible drawbacks. You mentioned a few. Another would be the need to apply the `order` property to flex items that otherwise wouldn't need it when ordering a group of items. I'm not really attached to re-setting `order` default. I have no problem dropping it. Thanks for the feedback. Answer revised.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed response. That clears up a lot, but I'm still not sure about spanning "columns" though. Say that I wanted the pink element to take up two columns, which would mean the yellow element would be the same size as it is now, but on its own row, with the pink element on the row below it spanning two columns. Is that possible, or is that not how flexbox works?

Comment: Hi Gavin, I updated my answer to address spanning columns. If you still have questions let me know.